# In which reliable textbook I can find the derivation of the multi cells (more than 2X2) version of pearson's chi square test?

Tags: statistics, reference-request

I can't find the statement, proof and defintion in Dasgupta asymtotic statistics textbook (Springer press), however I found it mentioned somewhere in Dasgupta's textbook as a section title, where can I find its statement and derivation?

If not, can you try to state in an elementary level and derive here? Many Thanks for enligten me!

[image]

Comment: +1. Great question! I see you created a Materials Science proposal in the past. I really wish they allowed it to be launched. If you don't mind another attempt at a Materials proposal, would you be so kind to commit to this? https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=NTU5NWJhYzBmMjZmMDkzNTNjNDhiYmExZjNkNmViMzk2NDEyMzAwZDU5YzgzOGUyYjRhMmE4NmRhZDAwYTkyOD9810pPXnfkmWz7PG55whnmUw2s8awGjUkmNoE41hUt0. It started slow but lately it's been booming with 5 commitments/day and very soon it will reach 200.